# If a wildcard search only matches one tag, the "Questions tagged" header retains the asterisks

Tags: bug, tags, search, wildcards

There is a single tag which matches the wildcard tag search [`[*owntim*]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*owntim*): [downtime](/questions/tagged/downtime). Making that search gives me this:

[image: search bug explained below]

I've circled the interesting bits. The wildcard's auto-expansion has, as expected, returned only `[downtime]`. That's what appears in the SE search bar. The questions that show up are simply the questions tagged with [downtime](/questions/tagged/downtime). Indeed, I've been redirected to the tagged-questions page for [downtime](/questions/tagged/downtime)... mostly.

The excerpt shown is the [downtime](/questions/tagged/downtime) excerpt, consistent with the idea of this simply being the tagged-questions page for [downtime](/questions/tagged/downtime). But, the URL is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*owntim*` - a tagged-questions page for the [*owntim*] tag. This is also the name given in the heading, "Questions tagged [*owntim*]". Except that's not the name of the tag!

For comparison, when doing a wildcard search which matches multiple tags, e.g. [`[*time]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time+or+downtime), the page that results is a search-results-page, not a tagged-questions page:

[image: search results page showing questions tagged "time" and "downtime"]

The bug here is that when the search only matches a single tag, the tagged-questions page for that tag appears, but acts as if the name of the tag is the verbatim search performed, up to retaining the wildcard asterisk characters.

Asterisked names even override synonymization: now that [downtime](/questions/tagged/downtime) is a [synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/maintenance/synonyms) of [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance), searching for [`[*owntim*]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*owntim*) brings up a page titled "Questions tagged [*owntim*]" but which uses the [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) excerpt. Searching for [`[downtime]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/downtime) brings up the [tagged-questions page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) for [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance)

The same bug is produced when there is only an asterisk on a single end of the tag search, as well as when the searcher is not logged in to the site.

Comment: This might be related (MSO): [Sad issue with UI while searching for \[foo*\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402316/sad-issue-with-ui-while-searching-for-foo)